# Multiples iFrames y "104: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: php, html, seguridad, nginx, iframe

Me pregunto si a alguien más le ha sucedido lo siguiente..

Supongamos que tenemos dominio A y B;

```
A -> homesite.com
B -> embebedsite.com
```

Si desde A, inserto varios iframes a B, el servicio de PHP se para con el error 104: Connection reset by peer.

Sin embargo cuando hacemos lo mismo, pero en el código html de A le indicamos un "id" distinto a cada iframe, entonces el servicio funciona.

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo?, ¿Se puede tratar de un caso de iFrame Injection?, ¿Sería posible una solución sin necesidad de añadir "id" en los iframes de A?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude observar por qué se producía la caída del servicio.

Los códigos javascript que hay dentro de los iframes solicitan peticiones asíncronas de los recursos, y por esta razón el servicio PHP acababa cayendo puesto que no puede atender los recursos y derivarlos al mismo tiempo a cada solicitud de iframe.

Después de varias pruebas, entendí cuáles factores ayudar a asimilaban mejor la situación y así solventar el problema, las detallo a continuación;

> - Añadir "id" a las etiquetas de "iframe".
> - Evitar el atributo "async" en los "script" javascript, o librerias que carguen los recursos de esta forma.
> - En el servicio de PHP, cambiar la escucha de servicio por TCP, en lugar de socket. ( "file.sock" a "127.0.0.1:9000" )
> - Aumentar tiempos de espera relacionados con las peticiones ( en el servicio web, apache, nginx etc)

Un Saludo.